# young generation is larger than old generation

Tags: jvm

I am analyzing the JVM performance by using jstat, I found in my system that the 'ec' (eden capacity) size is larger than 'oc'(old capacity), below is all my settings:
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=256M 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m

is it possible that ec is larger than oc? Or there are more than one oc??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That depends and no harm in either of them. You might be generating loads of transient objects..

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and it is not necessarily bad.